# I broke compatibility with Dotfuscator...please help me understand how

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crash, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I've used Visual Studio 2010 to create Windows programs using C# for over 18 months now. For at least 12 of those months, I've been using the community edition of Dotfuscator to obfuscate all my programs. So far it's worked beautifully.

My latest project was released in its initial beta, compiled with Visual Studio 2010 for .NET Framework 4.0. That was obfuscated fine.

Since then I imported that to Visual Studio 2013, moved it to .NET Framework 4.5.1 and then kept working on my debugging version. When I was ready for another beta release to my users, I come to realize that the obfuscated version crashes in its release state. The unobsfucated version in release form does not crash. If I put the obfuscated EXE to replace the debugging version, Visual Studio gives me a warning but then runs the program just fine. No crash.

Even though I have an UnhandledException handler in Program.cs, the program just crashes and Windows gives me nothing more than a assembly line reference. Nothing I can use to narrow down the cause.

I have since moved the program back to Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4.0, .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, tried all variations of settings in Dotfuscator. Tried the Pro Edition of Dotfuscator (14 day trial). Nothing. After obfuscation, crash with no usable information. Even if I excluse everything, so 0.0% is renamed, still get a crash.

I have some encryption information that needs to remain obfuscated as it has been for the past year or so. So I need to get obfuscation working. And I simply can't figure out what happened, or what I did, to make it stop working.

I would highly appreciate some guidance on what could have been. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here are the very basic and not very helpful error messages. I can follow a stack trace if one were provided. I also have my code covered in generous amounts of error catchers, plus a general AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException handler. Still, this is all I get:

http://www.keepitfishy.com/files/crash1.jpg

http://www.keepitfishy.com/files/crash2.jpg

and this is part of the assembly code I get when I try to debug with Visual Studio, I marked the line that is supposed to be the culprit:

```
7362CEF1 E8 15 05 00 00       call        7362D40B  
7362CEF6 59                   pop         ecx  
7362CEF7 68 09 04 00 C0       push        0C0000409h  
7362CEFC E8 16 05 00 00       call        7362D417  
7362CF01 59                   pop         ecx  
7362CF02 5D                   pop         ebp  
7362CF03 C3                   ret  
7362CF04 55                   push        ebp  
7362CF05 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
7362CF07 81 EC 24 03 00 00    sub         esp,324h  
7362CF0D 6A 17                push        17h  
7362CF0F E8 37 DE C3 FF       call        7326AD4B  
7362CF14 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
7362CF16 74 05                je          7362CF1D  
7362CF18 6A 02                push        2  
7362CF1A 59                   pop         ecx  
[error line]7362CF1B CD 29                int         29h[error line]
7362CF1D A3 58 61 75 73       mov         dword ptr ds:[73756158h],eax  
7362CF22 89 0D 54 61 75 73    mov         dword ptr ds:[73756154h],ecx  
7362CF28 89 15 50 61 75 73    mov         dword ptr ds:[73756150h],edx  
7362CF2E 89 1D 4C 61 75 73    mov         dword ptr ds:[7375614Ch],ebx  
7362CF34 89 35 48 61 75 73    mov         dword ptr ds:[73756148h],esi  
7362CF3A 89 3D 44 61 75 73    mov         dword ptr ds:[73756144h],edi  
7362CF40 8C 15 70 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[73756170h],ss  
7362CF46 8C 0D 64 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[73756164h],cs  
7362CF4C 8C 1D 40 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[73756140h],ds  
7362CF52 8C 05 3C 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[7375613Ch],es  
7362CF58 8C 25 38 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[73756138h],fs  
7362CF5E 8C 2D 34 61 75 73    mov         word ptr ds:[73756134h],gs  
7362CF64 9C                   pushfd  
7362CF65 8F 05 68 61 75 73    pop         dword ptr ds:[73756168h]  
7362CF6B 8B 45 00             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp]  
7362CF6E A3 5C 61 75 73       mov         dword ptr ds:[7375615Ch],eax  
7362CF73 8B 45 04             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+4]  
7362CF76 A3 60 61 75 73       mov         dword ptr ds:[73756160h],eax  
7362CF7B 8D 45 08             lea         eax,[ebp+8]  
7362CF7E A3 6C 61 75 73       mov         dword ptr ds:[7375616Ch],eax  
7362CF83 8B 85 DC FC FF FF    mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-324h]
```

If anyone can help me decipher that, I can perhaps track down the cause. Thanks.

Comment: What is the crash?  Not much to go on here.

Comment: @Mitch, good point. Added some screengrabs and part of the assembly debug code. I have no idea how that's supposed to help me interpret anything. Whatever happened to stack traces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the error dialog you posted, you are having stack issues in native code:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx):

> 0xC0000409 STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN
>
> The system detected an
>   overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun
>   could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

Tracking down what is causing the overrun may be as simple as looking at the stack trace when the exception is thrown.  Even though VS is not showing you code, it may still be able to [identify the module and function on the top off the call stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx).

If the issue is from corruption of the stack which has long since passed, you may need to approach the issue not from .Net, but as any other native application.

If you are not the author of any native components in your application, you may have a P/Invoke signature which is incorrect, be allocating an incorrectly sized buffer or struct which is passed to a P/Invoked function, or otherwise be calling native code incorrectly.  Check your P/Invokes and make sure you have [MDAs enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm still confused as to how this is a problem when running the release version but not the debug version. And only when running the obfuscated release version, as the un-obfuscated release version works.
In any case, can't get to the call stack. This is all I can see: 
> clr.dll!7362cf1b()  
No matter what things I've tried to change, by removing some of the references, commenting out the code, the error has been the exact same every time. So it's probably just one bad line somewhere. But nothing that neither Visual Studio nor ReSharper is screaming at. Any other ideas?

Comment: I enabled all MDAs and my code that uses the DevIL.dll library is unbalancing the stack. Unfortunately I don't know how I can do this different. I'm using code that I got online to be able to interface with DevIL.dll, as it's not recognized by .NET. Here's a sample of how I use it in one of the calls I'm making that is unbalancing the stack:

Ilu.iluImageParameter(Ilu.ILU_FILTER, scaler);

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("bin\\ILU.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void iluImageParameter(int PName, int Param);

All other calls look the same...

Comment: You could get this error just compiling with a different revision of the compiler.  Native issues are sensitive to packing, ordering, and alignment issues which can appear or disappear at will.  Since the only thing on the call stack is the current IP, someone partied on the current stack frame.

Comment: All of the DevIL exports are `__stdcall`, but you are specifying the use of `cdecl`.

Comment: I was about to post that I had managed to fix it. To be clear, I wasn't doing any specification. That's just copy/pasted code that I've used for at least 12 months now, including on earlier versions of this program. But I altered the calls, and for the first time ever my code can run with all MDAs enabled without any inbalance (so I'll carry this improvement to my other programs). I was able to obfuscate and run the program now! I'll mark your answer since it essentially pointed me at the culprit. Thanks!